# Why is my .bash_profile breaking when a new "screen" session is made?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, terminal

[image: New Terminal Window]

[image: New screen session]

**file** : `~/.bash_profile` ([.bash_profile](https://ideone.com/87zycl))

Whenever I create a new `screen` session on my Mac, the terminal window would display

```
bash: git_color: command not found
bash: git_branch: command not found
```

Why is the function `git_color` and `git_branch` is not getting executed on the `screen` session?

Is there any alternative to achieve it?

Comment: For the future, questions about configuring and using your interactive shell environment are a better fit for our sister site [unix.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about how `screen` works.

What seems is that `.bash_profile` doesn't get executed as `screen` is not creating a login shell. [1]

Going by the general bash rules, `PS1` is being read by the shell issued by `screen` because you exported it.

i.e., you did this:

```
export PS1
```

Do the same for your functions. [2]

Add 2 commands to your `.bash_profile` after you have defined both the functions:

```
export -f git_color
export -f git_branch
```

Alternatively, add those functions and `PS1` to `.bashrc` as well.

[1] [About .bash_profile and .bashrc](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc)

[2] [Exporting functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/can-i-export-functions-in-bash)

Comment: Alternative move `git_color` and `git_branch` from `.bash_profile` to `.bashrc`